# What can I do if underestimated the project ?

Tags: freelance-websites

I took a project, and I estimate it at a certain price.
Problem is, I really largely underestimate it, because of me, and some area where the client was not very clear.

I did it on a freelancer website, so I can't modify the price anymore, and I almost did at least 60 % of the project.

What are my options ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Finish the project for the agreed upon amount and learn from your
   mistake.
2. Ask for more money or stop working on the project, and create an
   unhappy client which will probably have other ramifications.